# Unexpected behaviour from if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have a simple if statement as follows:

```
if (!state.wasGroundedLastFrame && _speed.y > 0){
    _newPosition.y += _speed.y * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

But as you can see in the image below that it’s entering the block even when `_speed.y` is less than 0.[image]
What could I be doing wrong?

I using MonoDevelop with Unity in C#

EDIT: 
To further clarify, `_speed` is a private Vector3 variable. In the screenshots below you can see that the value doesn’t change at the time of evaluating the condition, and in the block. The value is calculated before this statement is called.[image: Evaluating the condition][image: In the block]

Another odd thing I just noticed is that when there is no user input this value should be constant (-3.33); it represents the current speed of the character. When I create a breakpoint, in the first frame the value is usually between 0, and -1. However in all the subsequent frames, when I continue execution without removing the breakpoint, the value is -3.33, the “correct” constant value.

Comment: Please provide a *complete* reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: Is _speed.y accessed by multiple threads?

Comment: What is the Datatype for y

Comment: In case @Kimi's question doesn't hint enough at a possible problem: If `_speed.y` is accessed by multiple threads, since there is no apparent synchronization happening, `_speed.y > 0` could have evaluated to `true` in the conditional and then `_speed.y`'s value was changed by another thread before line 184 was reached in execution on this thread.

Comment: @user2526236: datatype for `y` is `float` according to the debug window screenshot.

Comment: Your screenshot does not show that it has entered the if block yet. You may want to check if it really enters the block, which is the next statement.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose - note the yellow horizontal arrow to the left of line number 184.

Comment: @Kimi It’s not accessed by multiple threads, it’s a private variable.

Comment: that is odd indeed. Sometimes abnormal problem needs abnormal answers. Try adding isNot opperator, since you added isNot in your first condition.

Comment: @user14492 private variables *can* be accessed by multiple threads. Is there a timer callback or some other method indirectly setting the value?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things I can think of that may be causing this issue:

1. Your code and compiled version are out of sync.  Not sure how to build on MonoDevelop with Unity, but my guess is that it is similar to other IDEs.  So do a 'Clean' and a 'Rebuild All' and re-run to see if you encounter the same problem.
2. You have multiple threads accessing and changing the value for _speed.y.  In order to solve that problem, put a lock() around the entire if statement as shown below.  You will also need to put the same lock around any code that changes the value for `_speed`

`private object SpeedLock = new object();`

...

`lock(SpeedLock){
   if (!state.wasGroundedLastFrame && _speed.y > 0){
       _newPosition.y += _speed.y * Time.deltaTime;
   }
}`